# javac: invalid target release: 13

Tags: java, netbeans

I have been working on some class projects on a work computer with NetBeans 11 and uploading my progress to github. Recently, I came home and pulled my progress down to my laptop which still has netbeans 8. All of a sudden, when I try to run code, I get:

```
javac: invalid target release: 13
```

From browsing stackoverflow and other such forums, I gather that 13 refers to the version of the JDK. Apparently, there is some mismatch in my settings (either I am using an old version but NetBeans wants to use something newer, or maybe the other way around).

I went into `project > properties > sources` and saw a drop down bar titled "Source/Binary Format" with JDK 13 selected. I dropped it down to 9 (a completely random choice) and then tried to run my code again. Voila, it worked.

My questions are simply: **What did I just do? Why did it work? Are there any implications for my program to be considered?**

If you choose to answer please be aware that I know little about the inner workings of Java, and so a simple explanation is appreciated. I only know how to write the code, not what happens behind the scenes. I'm tempted to blindly plow forward with my coding, but I thought this might be a learning point. Perhaps not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, your IDE checks your code according to the rules of the language, and those those are different depending on language version because e.g. Java 7 has no lambdas but Java 8 does. Your project was configured to be checked against the rules for Java 13, but the older version of NetBeans wasn't able to do that, so you've asked for it to be checked against the rules for Java 9 instead. This will have no impact on your project unless you want to use features introduced in Java 10 or later.

The other purpose of this drop-down menu is if you want to compile your project so that it can be run using an older version of Java. If you're distributing a piece of software for users who still only have Java 8 installed, then you would want to limit the project to Java 8.